# About computer science and category theory

Tags: programming-languages, category-theory

I read that Category Theory has alot to do with how programs and information can be organised.Can Category theory simplify various programming strategies? If a specific Category is represented as a directed graph is this similar to flow charts used in programming?

Comment: Look up monads and arrows and applicative functors in the Haskell world.

Comment: [Another related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138/natural-occurrences-of-monads-that-make-use-of-the-category-theoretical-framewor?rq=1).